Local font works perfectly on Chrome, not loading on Safari and iOS phone, using Nextjs?
I am using next local font as per the documentation:
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const dyuthi = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: '../public/fonts/Dyuthi-Regular.ttf',
    },
    {
      path: '../public/fonts/Dyuthi-Regular.woff',
    },
    {
      path: '../public/fonts/Dyuthi-Regular.woff2',
    }
  ],
  variable: '--font-dyuthi'
})


export default function Title() {
    return (
        <div className="font-dyuthi">
          My Title With Special Font
        </div>
    )
  }
}

As I said, the font is working on Google Chrome, it doesnt work on Safari and iOS. Moreover, when I go to Safari dev tools -> Sources -> Fonts the font name is auto generated and when I click on it gives me "An error occured trying to load the resource"
Can you point me what I am doing wrong?
